# how to change the font color within a function jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following function which highlights to the user in red what parts of the form are still required to be filled out

```
<script>
    $('#audit_submit').click(function () {
    $('.required').css('background-color', '#57ff89');
    $('.required').filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.value) === '';
    }).css('background-color', '#ff4545');
$('.required').css('color', 'white');
});
</script>
```

My issue now is the font colour by default is black when the text-input is highlighted in red as shown in the image below. I wish to make font colour white however I'm not sure how to do it using the above method or even convert the defined styles into its own css sheet

[image]

Comment: I would recommend using css, then add a class when required (`required`) and the css can define what the required class should look like

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Swtich CSS class and set styles in .css file. Not inline.

Comment: @pavel how would I convert it to use a style sheet? I have never actually done that before

Comment: @Opal_Ding: Instead of `.css(...)` work with `addClass/removeClass`. Or if fields are required, use `required` attribute and in CSS `:valid/:invalid` to style correctly/incorrectly filled input. No JS needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.required').css('color', 'white');
```

Comment: I tried this but I might be putting it in the wrong place. See my updated question

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a style sheet

jquery

```
<script>
 $('#audit_submit').click(function () {
    $('input').addClass('your-class');
  $('.required').css('background-color', '#fff');
  $('.required').filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.value) === '';
  }).css({"background-color": "red", "color::placeholder": "white"});
});
</script>
```

css

```
.your-class::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: #ffffff
    }
```

[image]